# FreeBSD package installation offline

Tags: package-management, freebsd

I am trying to learn FreeBSD and have been trying to install xorg-minimal, gedit and libreoffice offline for a couple of weeks now (read manual) and just keep going around in circles. It is a new install of FreeBSD 10. Is there anyone here who will take the time to help and go through the basics for me?

I have saved xorg-minimal-7.5.2.tbz and gedit and libreoffice to disk and also succeeded in installing pkg-1.8.3.

During my last attempt, I edited a `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/FreeBSD.conf` like this:

```
FreeBSD: {
  enabled: no
}
```

and then edited `/usr/local/etc/pkg/repos/<fileName>.conf` like this:

```
file name: {
  url: file:///.../.../.../<packages>/
  enabled: yes
}
```

When I try to use `pkg install`, I get errors like these:

```
pkg: file:/.../.../meta.txz : No such file or directory
pkg: repository ... has no meta file,
pkg: file:/.../.../digests.txz: No such file or directory
pkg: ///xorg-minimal-7.5.2.tbz is not a valid package: no manifest found
```

Like I said, I have tried so many things, I am starting to feel a little punch drunk and it would not surprise me if I am leaving out some critical step.

Answer (score 5):

`pkg` relies on various metadata files that you don't have on your local machine, because they are downloaded from a configured package repository. I think the best solution here is to revert to using the default FreeBSD repo, and simply use the `pkg add` command, which will attempt to install a package from a local package archive file, instead of `pkg install`, which will search your configured repos and attempt to install a package from a remote source.

Incidentally, you can also use `pkg fetch` to download package archive files from a configured repo, for installation later using `pkg add`:

```
# pkg fetch -d zsh

# pkg add /var/cache/pkg/zsh-5.0.7_2.txz
```

The `-d` flag to `pkg fetch` tells `pkg` to download any dependencies that may be required to successfully install the named package. Note that by default, packages downloaded in this manner are stashed in `/var/cache/pkg`, and you'll need to include the path to the archive file when you call `pkg add`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried installing Internet, but did not succeed. That's why I tried the offline route. I tried to vote up your answer, but I don't have enough reputation points here. Sorry about that! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

It is a very simple step that you have missed.  Simply use the `--no-repo-update` option to `pkg install`.  Make sure, when on-line, that your repository indexes are up-to-date, of course.  And use `pkg fetch` or `pkg install --fetch-only` to fetch the package files when on-line, similarly.