# How to install Xfce from xfce-4.10.tar.bz2 (downloading file) in terminal FreeBSD without internet?

Tags: freebsd

I install FreeBSD but in OS not GUI and I haven't internet but I downloaded xfce in internet-cafe from official site file xfce-4.10.tar.bz2 and I want to install xfce without internet from file ! Please help me ! (^_^)

Answer (score 1):

> I want to install xfce without internet from file !

Then use [the x11-wm/xfce4 port](https://freebsd.org/ports/x11-wm.html#xfce-4.12_1) that is both *right there* in the Ports tree at `/usr/ports/x11-wm/xfce4` and more up to date than version 4.10.  `make fetch` will download the source on-line which you can later install off-line.  You will probably need `make fetch-recursive` if you want things like the x11/xfce4-terminal port as well.

Or install the equivalent binary packages.  `pkg fetch` or `pkg install --fetch-only` will download the binary archives on-line which can be later installed off-line.  Remember to use the `--no-repo-update` option to `pkg install` when off-line.

## Further reading

- "[Using the Ports Collection](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/ports-using.html)". *FreeBSD Handbook*.  FreeBSD.  2017.
- *[About FreeBSD Ports](https://freebsd.org/ports/)*.  FreeBSD.  2015-11-25.
- [How to install and configure FreeBSD without internet access?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/215699/)
- [FreeBSD package installation offline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181954/)
- [`pkg`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg).  *FreeBSD Manual*.  FreeBSD.  2015-10-31.

Comment: I can't download source on-line with FreeBSD, Xfce tar.bz2 file I downloaded in another computer with another internet connection I said my friend I haven't internet ! Could you advice me how to install downloaded file xfce-4.12.tar.bz2 ?

Comment: Actually, all that you said was that you had FreeBSD and used an Internet cafe.  You said _nothing_ about using multiple machines.  You need to edit your question to state what you are doing _properly and completely_.

Comment: May be he mean he can not connect to the Internet from his computer and went to the Internet cafe for downloading the source code of Xfce ! @JdeBP Do not insult this person !

Answer (score 0):

[pkg-add(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pkg-add&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD-Ports) can install from a file, **however** things such as the Xfce desktop environment require more than a single package. See, for example:

- https://www.freshports.org/x11-wm/xfce4/#dependencies

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a small "local" customized repository (and burn it to CD/DVD) with just a subset of packages and dependencies needed to install Xfce or Firefox or whatever.

Detailed procedure and full script here: https://gist.github.com/kalabic/c770beb872a3833293e8672f9b80c839

But, in short:

- First, on one Internet connected FreeBSD machine create this local repository using script from the linked page. (And save to USB, burn to CD/DVD, etc)
- Second, on air-gaped PC assuming you will mount this ISO or CD to '/mnt', edit '/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf' accordingly.
- That's it, try pkg install whatever.